# How can I convert json format in html code to text

Tags: javascript, json

When I stored json data in mysql as string:

```
{"time":1641959106166,"blocks":[{"id":"Q6Z-TKWLup","type":"embed","data":{"service":"youtube","source":"https://youtu.be/tbXpX4dAqjg","embed":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbXpX4dAqjg","width":580,"height":320,"caption":"This is a tutorial for learning PHP Symfony framework."}}],"version":"2.22.2"}
```

When I print out in console.log, it looks

```
{&quot;time&quot;:1641957539439,&quot;blocks&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;ztUBHu3HHg&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;table&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;withHeadings&quot;:false,&quot;content&quot;:[[&quot;Category&quot;,&quot;Language&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;,&quot;Java&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;,&quot;Python&quot;]]}}],&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2.22.2&quot;}
```

How can I convert to the original json text? I need it to do javascript function.

```
<script>
posts = ["{&quot;time&quot;:1641959106166,&quot;blocks&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Q6Z-TKWLup&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;embed&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;service&quot;:&quot;youtube&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;https://youtu.be/tbXpX4dAqjg&quot;,&quot;embed&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbXpX4dAqjg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:580,&quot;height&quot;:320,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;This is a tutorial for learning PHP Symfony framework.&quot;}}],&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2.22.2&quot;}","{&quot;time&quot;:1641957539439,&quot;blocks&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;ztUBHu3HHg&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;table&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;withHeadings&quot;:false,&quot;content&quot;:[[&quot;Category&quot;,&quot;Language&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;,&quot;Java&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;,&quot;Python&quot;]]}}],&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2.22.2&quot;}","{&quot;time&quot;:1641955404060,&quot;blocks&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;t_39IX2iIH&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;header&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;First Blog Post&quot;,&quot;level&quot;:2}},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;jBunZLMaJC&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;paragraph&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;gogogo&quot;}}],&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2.22.2&quot;}"]
console.log(JSON.parse(posts));
</script>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse

Comment: You should fix this by storing the strings properly in your database, not by fixing this when you display it client side.

Comment: is it not good to store in string?

Comment: It's wrong to store it html-encoded with html entities.